# How updating dynamic framework will affect App Store build

Tags: ios, app-store, ios-frameworks, ios-library

I have an app on the App Store and I have to create another app. This other app has some of the same functionalities as the first app. So I wanted to create a framework to put the common code in and use it inside the apps. Unfortunately, this framework has to change to add more features and improvements.

I saw that dynamic libraries can update the library code without any change to an app already pushed to the App Store. But this is reserved for Apple. Also, since iOS 8, we can create a dynamic framework which includes dynamic libraries. So is it possible to have the same, meaning if I update my dynamic framework, it also updates the app without having to push to the App Store again and face app review process?

If not, do you have some clues/recommendation to achieve that?

Comment: Interesting, where you read/saw "dynamic libraries can update the library code without any change on app already pushed on App Store"

Comment: Here for exemple (sentence highlighted in green) : https://medium.com/@zippicoder/libraries-frameworks-swift-packages-whats-the-difference-764f371444cd
But after it mention that only Apple is able to do that

Comment: I guess that sentence is saying when you update you iOS version then app will automatically linked to latest system frameworks(e.g UIKit)

Comment: Af far i know once you submit app to the app store then you can't change single line of code in that app

Comment: Yes that's why I was confused. Dynamic library can do that but we cannot create them directly without framework but dynamic framework embed dynamic library so I was lost a bit on, is it really impossible :D

Comment: Also Swift is statically typed language(not like java script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic Framework is a bit different from the understanding you have. Please read apple documents in more detail for that.

Currently only way to achieve what you expect is to push code on App Store as hidden, and based on some server API configuration update your content accordingly (Firebase Remote Config is one such good example if security is not that big a concern)

Comment: I see your point, thank you! So currently if I integrate my framework to a client app, the client have to push to Appstore his app each time I do an update on my framework, and there is no way to change that ?

Comment: No way to change that. Any change in dynamic framework code needs to be pushed to App Store each time